# After turn macbook into iBeacon not finding using PheripheralManager / CBCentralManager

Tags: ios, macos, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

I have turned my mac book pro into iBeacon using the project https://github.com/mttrb/BeaconOSX but unable to list the Mac device in iPhone using PheripheralManager / CBCentralManager after scan.

Could you please help me understand why the Mac Book is not listed?

Edit: I am using MacBook Pro with 10.9.1 Mac OS, my bluetooth version listed under system preference is LMP Version is 0x6

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know for a fact that your MacBook Pro has BLE hardware?  You need not only an OS version which supports this, but hardware as well, and if your machine is older with an upgraded OS, you may not have that capability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try known working programs on both the iOS and OSX Mavericks sides.  On the iOS side, try our free [Locate for iBeacon](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/locate-for-ibeacon/id738709014?mt=8) app as @sage444 suggests.  If that does not detect your transmitter, try our [MacBeacon](http://www.radiusnetworks.com/macbeacon-app.html) app. It is $10, but we guarantee it will work with a BLE capable Mavericks computer or we will give you a refund.

One final thought, make sure you have the proper ProximityUUID from the BeaconOSX program in your region in your iOS program, or you will not see the beacon.

Comment: I am able to locate Macbook using CLLocationManager & CLBeaconRegion but when i scan for a peripheral device using PheripheralManager & CBCentralManager its not listing the Macbook.

Comment: OK, I understand now.  You want to use CoreBluetooth to detect the iBeacon.  Do you see any devices at all?  Understand that you will not be able to use CoreBluetooth to read the iBeacon's ProximityUUID.  If you are seeing a device with a different advertisement UUID, that may indeed be your iBeacon.  Read details in my blog post here: http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2013/10/21/corebluetooth-doesnt-let-you-see-ibeacons.html

Comment: so using CoreBluetooth the same proximity UUID is not obtained after scanning for peripherals. I have gone through the blog post its explained nicely, but couldn't understand the reason behind why after scanning the same proximity UUID is not discovered?

Comment: Despite the similarity in name and the way it looks, the  NSConcreteUUID returned by CoreBluetooth's [peripheral identifier] has nothing to do with the iBeacon's ProximityUUID.  It is a temporary identifier generated by iOS when the advertisement is detected.  If you disable the iBeacon and reenable it later, this identifier will actually change!  Unfortunately, as explained in the blog, you simply cannot read the iBeacon's ProximityUUID using CoreBluetooth on iOS.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should run Mavericks and have fresh mac book with BLE support, then get proper app to iPhone - search in app store for iBeacon

Comment: I am using MacBook Pro with Mac OS 10.9.1 and Bluetooth version i.e., LMP Version 0x6.

Comment: just for experiment, try "Locate iB" from app store